# NPM scripts not running sequentially

Tags: docker, npm, jestjs, npm-scripts, supertest

I'm writing e2e tests with Supertest for my NestJS application and I have a "test:e2e" script which looks like this:

```
"test:e2e": "nerdctl compose up && dotenv -e .env.test -- jest --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json && nerdctl compose down"
```

When I run the command `yarn test:e2e`, it stops after spinning up my docker container (from the `nerdctl compose up` command) and it doesn't run my tests or tear the container down. I know the double ampersands `&&` are used to run the scripts sequentially which is my goal here, but I can't seem to figure out why it stops after spinning up my docker container. Maybe perhaps spinning up the container takes too long? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Environment:

- macOS v12.6.1
- Node v18.12.1
- NPM v8.19.2

Comment: Does `nerdctl compose up` ever actually _finish_? If you just run that command does it exit, or do you have to explicitly terminate it?

Comment: I think the command needs to have the -d option to detach, so the docker program terminates, to allow the next task (dotenv) to run.

Comment: Yep how silly of me, I completely forgot that I needed to use the -d option to detach. Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I forgot to add the -d option to run my container in the background. Thank you Steven!